# How to convert the .fla Advanced Photo Album to html5 when it is heavier than 1024kb

Tags: ios, html, flash

As per my client's requirement, I had used flash as3.0 Advanced Photo Album in a website gallery, But Flash is not compatible on Apple's gadget's like iPhone, iMac, iPad etc.

I have gone thought internet and found that "SWIFFY" can convert the files to HTML5, but limit is 1024 kb. and my file is 4.5 mb. How can I reduce flash file size to that limit so that I can convert file.